# Стандартные иконки Android

Tags: android

Где можно найти перечень всех иконок в Android? Может есть сайт или папка в SDK?

Comment: Вопрос-клон на en-SO: [Where can i find and download Material Design icons for my Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975587/where-can-i-find-and-download-material-design-icons-for-my-android-app)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так на что переименовать?

Comment: Переименовывать не надо! Пусть будут разные заголовки. Тогда гугл будет на запросы `Стандартные иконки Android` и `Где найти иконки для Android приложений в стиле Material` выдавать ссылку на ответ нужный. И где мой плюсик в ответе по ссылке из причины закрытия? И на en-SO тоже хочу! И в вопрос и в ответ! =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заскочите в соседний вопрос.